# Array en PHP con json_encode para insertar en Gráfica

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo un archivo index.php que utilizo ajax para procesar los datos que me vienen de otro archivo .php el código es el siguiente:

```
 $.ajax({
 url:'process.php',
 method:"POST",
 dataType: "json",
 data:{month:month, year:year, seriennummer:seriennummer},
 success:function(data)
{

            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart(data));

          }
        });
```

En el mismo archivo otro script que tengo la función de crear el gráfico:

```
<script>

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  function drawChart(response) {   

    var data2 = [['Dias', 'Cantidad']];
         for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                data2[i + 1] = response[i];  
         }
         console.info(data2);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([data2]);

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Titulo',
        subtitle: 'Subtitulo',
      },
      bars: 'vertical',
      vAxis: {format: 'decimal'},
      height: 400,
      colors: ['#00cc44', '#d95f02', '#7570b3']
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('Grafico'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

  }
</script>
```

Este es el fragmento de código implementado en un archivo process.php que me devuelve los resultados de una consulta a MySQL:

```
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $output[][] .= "['".$row{'Day'}."',".$row{'Sum_Day'}."],";
     }

    echo json_encode($output, true);
```

En la consola puedo ver el resultado de data2 que es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de momento me muestra el gráfico sin valores.
¿Alguna ayuda?, Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El json_encode convierte un array a un String JSON, al concatenar el resultado de tu consulta como lo haces con el $output lo tratas como String, tendrias que intentar como

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($output, array($row["Day"],$row["Sum_Day"]))
}

echo json_encode($output, true);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero de esta forma me devuelve null

Comment: El array te devuelve null o el json_encode?

Comment: El json_encode me devuelve null.

Comment: Probaste hacer un var_dump para ver si el array esta mal formado?

Comment: Acabo de probar var_dump y me devuelve 30 veces null, ya que son 30 valores que hay en el select

Comment: Esta declada la variable $output = array();  antes del WHILE?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76905/discussion-between-jack-and-f-sola).